# How to add Bcc and Cc to mail that sent by 'core/email_template' model send()

Tags: email-templates, send-mail

I am sending mail by following code,

```
$template = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('customer_email');
$template->addSenderName("MyName");
$template->addSenderEMail("myname@gmail.com");
$template->send("tomail@some.com","toname",$data);
```

Can i add Bcc and Cc to this $template.if yes or no how it can be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `->addBcc()` on the template object to set the bcc recipient.  There isn't an equivalent cc method, you instead can pass an array for the email addresses and an array for the names to the `->send()` method:

```
$template = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('customer_email');
$template->addSenderName("MyName");
$template->addSenderEMail("myname@gmail.com");
$template->addBcc("some@email.com");
$template->send(array("tomail@some.com","someother@email.com"),array("toname",$othername),$data);
```

Comment: just now I saw that method, anyway thank you for your time..

Answer (score 0):

You can add **cc** and **bcc** in your email using the following piece of code

```
$template = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('email_template_identifier');
$template->getMail()->addCc('your.cc.email@example.com');
$template->addBcc('your.bcc.email@example.com');
```